# Availability of els.dll / elscore.dll on Windows container images

Tags: containers, azure-container-service, azure-container-registry, windows-server-2019, container-image

I recently deployed a container to Azure, and when I run the application (a website) I encounter the exception...

> Unable to load DLL 'elscore.dll': The specified module could not be found.

Sure enough, if I start a powershell session on the deployment and `dir` my way around I can see that elscore.dll (and els.dll) are not present.

The container image is built using `4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019`, and below is the Dockerfile used to build the image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
ENV chocolateyUseWindowsCompression false
  
RUN md "c:\SiteInstall"
  
COPY SetupSite.ps1 c:/SiteInstall
  
WORKDIR c:/SiteInstall
  
RUN powershell .\SetupSite.ps1 -verbose
  
EXPOSE 80
```

Does anyone know of a way in which I can install ELS ([Extended Linguistic Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/about-extended-linguistic-services))? I can't find any way of adding it to Windows.

Alternatively, any suggestions for which image I could use which would include this? Is my image a cut-down version, and if so is there a full version image?

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile you use to create the image?

Comment: Done - added to the OP.

Comment: Do you check the Dockerfile of the base image if it installed the ELS?

Comment: I know that it's not in the base image that I'm using - that's why I'm asking if anyone knows of images which _do_ contain ELS.dll.

Comment: It's not the necessary service. I'm afraid you need to install yourself to customize the image.